# Select from Table1, Table2

Tags: sql, select

I found the following query. What does this mean?

```
select * from table1, table2
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is called a *CROSS JOIN*, but it is using old syntax with `,` in the `FROM` clause. My advice is not to use old syntax; stick with the `JOIN` here.

It produces a [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product), so the number of rows in the result set will be the number of rows from `table1` multiplied by number of rows from `table2` (assuming there aren't any constraints in the `WHERE` clause). It effectively pairs each row from `table1` with a row coming from `table2`.

The below query is an equivalent, but it does explicit `JOIN` operation which separates the constraint logic of data retrieval (normally put within the `WHERE` clause) from the logic of connecting related data stored across separate tables (within the `FROM` clause):

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
CROSS JOIN table2
```

Consider an example where `table1` has 8 rows and `table2` has 5 rows. In the output, you get 40 rows (8 rows * 5 rows), because it pairs all rows from both sources (tables).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

You will get all rows from table1 multiplied by all rows from table2, and it will display depending on the columns of both tables. As [sgeddes pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39859022/select-from-table1-table2/39859115#comment67005939_39859022), creating a Cartesian product.

Answer (score 2):

Table1

- (Col1, Col2), 4 Records

Table2

- (Col11, Col22, Col33), 3 Records

The query given below, will produce **Table1.records** x **Table2.records** (Cartesian Product):

```
select * from table1, table2
```

The result will be a table with:

- 5 columns : `Col1, Col2, Col11, Col22, Col33`
- 12 records: 4 x 3