# what operation does "select from table1, table2 " imply?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I know different joins, but I wanted to know which of them is being used when we run queries like this:

```
select * from table1 t1, table2 t2
```

is it full outer join or natural join for example?

Also does it have a unique meaning among different databases or all do the same?

---

**UPDATE**: what if we add `where` clause ? will it be always `inner join`?

Comment: CROSS JOIN, or a cartessian product. Every row in t1 joins with every row in t2.  Its a notation from 1992. Don't use it.

Comment: Without an explicit JOIN or WHERE this is essentially a CROSS JOIN

Comment: search,before asking, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39859022/select-from-table1-table2/39859096#39859096

Comment: @MajidVahidkhoo You are right but my question has two other parts too :) 
(does it have unique meaning among all databases ? + where clause)

Comment: The so-called duplicate of this question says what does it mean, this one says what operation does in imply. The answer to this question is, it implies the operation of 'product' (as in 'multiply').

Comment: ...@MatBailie: relational product as in 'multiply' is not the same as Cartesian Product - the latter results in set of all ordered pairs, whereas the former results in a relation (with a set of attributes, no pairs). Similarly in SQL, `CROSS JOIN` results in... well, this unnamed thing with perhaps duplicate columns but certainly no pairs!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The comma in the `from` clause -- by itself -- is equivalent to `cross join` in almost all databases.  So:

```
from table1 t1, table2 t2
```

is functionally equivalent to:

```
from table1 t1 cross join table2 t2
```

They are not *exactly* equivalent, because the scoping rules within the `from` clause are slightly different.  So:

```
from table1 t1, table2 t2 join
     table3 t3
     on t1.x = t3.x
```

generates an error, whereas the equivalent query with `cross join` works.

In general, conditions in the `WHERE` clause will always result in the `INNER JOIN`.  However, some databases have extended the syntax to support outer joins in the `WHERE` clause.

I can think of one exception where the comma does *not* mean `CROSS JOIN`.  Google's BigQuery originally used the comma for `UNION ALL`.  However, that is only in Legacy SQL and they have removed that in Standard SQL.

Commas in the `FROM` clause have been out of fashion since the 1900s.  They are the "original" form of joining tables in SQL, but explicit `JOIN` syntax is much better.

To me, they also mean someone who learned SQL decades ago and refused to learn about outer joins, or someone who has learned SQL from ancient materials -- and doesn't know a lot of other things that SQL does.

Comment: Just for personal interest: Can you please tell me what are the databases that expand the syntax for outer joins? And how it looks like?

Comment: @S-Man . . . Actually, I won't.  That syntax is obsolete.  If databases still support it, the vendors discourage using it.  Learn to use proper explicit `JOIN` syntax, unless your specific interest is in the history of the SQL language (rather than getting something done).

Answer (score 5):

[demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d89fbcd25fe81f8cef8a38b180fefa1f)

This is a `CROSS JOIN` (cartesian product). So both of the following queries are equal

```
SELECT * FROM table1, table2              -- implicit CROSS JOIN
SELECT * FROM table1 CROSS JOIN table1    -- explicit CROSS JOIN
```

---

concerning **UPDATE**

A `WHERE` clause makes the general `CROSS JOIN` to an `INNER JOIN`. An `INNER JOIN` can be got by three ways:

```
SELECT * FROM table1, table2 WHERE table1.id = table2.id           -- implicit CROSS JOIN notation
SELECT * FROM table1 CROSS JOIN table2 WHERE table1.id = table2.id -- really unusual!: explicit CROSS JOIN notation
SELECT * FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON (table1.id = table2.id)  -- explicit INNER JOIN NOTATION
```

[Further reading (wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Cross_join)